# Не получается frame.dispose()

Tags: java

При нажатии на кнопке открывается новый фрейм, необходимо закрыть старый. Не получается `frame.dispose()`.

```
package com.company;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

/**
 * Created by vmorozov on 17.04.2016.
 */
public class StartPage {
    JButton buttonLogin;
    JButton buttonRegistration;


    public void log() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        buttonLogin = new JButton("Login");
        buttonRegistration = new JButton("Registration");


        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, buttonLogin);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, buttonRegistration);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(150, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        buttonLogin.addActionListener(new LoginListener());
        buttonRegistration.addActionListener(new RegisterListener());
    }
}

class LoginListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("login");
        LoginForm logg = new LoginForm();
        logg.log();

    }
}

class RegisterListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("registered");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
frame.setVisible(false);
frame.dispose();
```

Comment: Если этот код написать в actionPerformed то компилятор не видит frame.

Comment: @MorozovViktor Выведете фрейм как packagelocal поле